# Zoo Visitor Member Fields Not Updating

Tags: expresso-store, ee2, zoo-visitor

I am currently using ex-presso store and have mapped it to the zoo visitor fields. When i complete an order, the user shipping and billing details are not saved or updated at all.

I am using the `{exp:zoo_visitor:details {global:disable_categories}}` tag to surround the member info form and using the `{visitor:global:mbr_user_shipping_phone}` formatted tags for the values of the text boxes.

Is there anything I can look at to solve this? I don't know what I am missing?

Comment: I have also tried to the member_id="{member_id}" in the details tag, but still no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are updating the users member data stored in Zoo Visitor outside of the normal checkout process of Store you should be using the `{exp:zoo_visitor:update_form}` tag pair  instead of the `{exp:zoo_visitor:details}` tag pair. The update tags allows for:

> The update form tag can be used to update native member fields like
>   password, username, screen_name, email & all custom fields you have
>   defined in the member channel.

Full [docs](http://ee-zoo.com/docs/visitor/tags/update.html) on the update tag.

Something along the lines of:

```
{exp:zoo_visitor:update_form}
 Billing City: <input name="mbr_billing_city" type="text" value="" />
{/exp:zoo_visitor:update_form}
```

If you are trying to update the members data during the checkout process you can simply use Store's native checkout functionality to update the member data. Something along the lines of:

```
{exp:store:checkout}
 <label for="billing_city">Billing City</label>
 {field:billing_city}
{/exp:store:checkout}
```

Or if you want to create a custom input you could do:

```
{exp:store:checkout}
 <label for="billing_city">Billing City</label>
 <input type="text" name="billing_city" value="{billing_city}" class="whatever" />
{/exp:store:checkout}
```